# Qualtrics and Saving Custom Form Field Responses

Tags: qualtrics

I have created a custom form in Qualtrics using the html `<form>` tag.  I have not been able to get any of the text entered into the custom fields to save and display with the other data.
I know it is because I need the correct value for the `<form>` action attribute. I've searched through the Element Inspector trying to find the .php that is attached to a default text entry field but cannot find one.
Does anyone know how to find out what the .php the rest of the Qualtrics survey is using is or how to go about collecting the entries from a custom text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add your own input fields. If you want a text entry field or fields, add a text entry question. If you want to change the look/formatting of the questions use JavaScript or CSS styles to change them.

A second, less desirable option is to use JavaScript event listeners to save your custom fields to embedded data fields when they are updated using setEmbeddedData.